# Qt android communication through UDP

Tags: android, qt, sockets, udp

i am working on an app that will send a simple string through wifi from one android phone to another. I've started building it through UDP sockets but my question is.. qt supports already the wifi? or i have to put it in the application? because i did some research but couldn't find a related answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Qt doesn't differentiate between networking interfaces here. It opens sockets in a generic way, and the operating system's networking stack determines how to route the packets through interfaces. WiFi is not special in any way, and doesn't require explicit support from Qt.

TL;DR: What's so special about WiFi?

Comment: Ahhh, so i dont have to put anything special if the device is connected to wifi?! I am making a project for my university...communication between two android devices with RF...and my professor,i dont know why, asked me to make the application to work first through wifi!

Comment: @telis80 Do you have to do anything special on a random Linux machine if the traffic goes through WiFi? No. Well, Android is just Linux in this respect.

Comment: Thank you very much, solved me from quite a headache here mate :)